# Null reference error after scaffolding SQL tables into MVC models

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I received a null reference error after scaffolding models from a SQLServer database into an ASP.NET MVC project. I had previously migrated the database into SQLServer from MS Access, and I am not sure if the issue occurs from that or not. I have a file path and one of the table models in my `modelContext` file which I am sure is wrong but I don't know how to fix this error.

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.fk_task_order_)
                .WithMany(p => p.Task)
                .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.ss_id)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.fk_task_order_id)
                .HasConstraintName("Task$[C:\\Users\\00000\\OneDrive - Company Name\\Desktop\\base_be.accdb].{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}");
```

Comment: Is database SQLServer or Access? SQL is not a database, it is a language used by many db apps, including Access. I don't see any SQL in your question. Fix narrative and tags.

Comment: Database was transferred from access to SQLServer. Sorry for saying it incorrectly marc